# PowerPoint VBA change picture of inserted audio file

Tags: vba, image, powerpoint

I'm struggling with the following issue in Powerpoint:

1. I insert an audio file into a slide; the inserted shape looks like below:

[image]

2. I want to change the default picture (the speaker) with a picture loaded from a file. I can do this by going to "Audio format -> Change picture -> From a file" menu

[image]

3. The shape will now look like this, showing the picture loaded from file:

[image]

4. How can I do this from VBA code?

a) Using Fill.UserPicture is not working, as UserPicture is something else - the shape will look like this:

[image]

b) Using the classic technique of remembering original shape position, deleting it and replacing it with a new shape/picture doesn't work here, as it will also delete the audio.

Thank you for any suggestion,

Adrian

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [John SR Wilson](http://pptalchemy.co.uk), here is a working approach (as Change Picture is not exposed in vba):

```
Set oMed = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1) 'For example!
T = oMed.Top 
L = oMed.Left 
With oMed 
.MediaFormat.SetDisplayPictureFromFile ("PATH TO IMAGE") 
.Height = 40  ' image will be 100% of original size so resize to about 40 points (you can change the value if you want)
.Top = T 
.Left = L 
End With
```